# Ninject with ASP.Net webforms and MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, ninject

I want to use Ninject in a project which combines ASP.Net webforms and ASP.Net MVC. I'm using Ninject 2, but when I use NinjectHttpApplication from Ninject.Web.Mvc it complains when I use somethings like a PageBase that the Kernel is not created.

I have the following in the Global.asax and am unsure what to add.

```
public class MvcApplication : Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
    }
}
```

Does somebody has this working somewhere who could share some thoughts or code on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ruben told, I've put up a message on the Ninject Mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/317fc48387399aa6

The answer in short is, it unfortunately isn't really possible. However with a custom PageBase class you can make Property and Method injection possible (from Nate Kohari's answer in the Ninject Mailing List):

```
public abstract class PageBase : Page
{
  public IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }
  public PageBase() { Kernel = ...; }
  public void Page_Init() { Kernel.Inject(this); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Have a look in the source for both the Mvc and non-Mvc Ninject Extensions - the code is very short and neat

2) Go to the ninject mailing list and ask this question, together with what you've learned from the source. There'll be an answer or a patch lightening quick

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've doen 1, and tried to combine the two HttpApplications to one. But this does not "feel right". I've put a message on the Ninject Mailing list, will let you know when I get a useful reply.

Answer (score 0):

here are some very good resources on how to leverage DI in webforms that I had bookmarked some time ago:

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ioc_and_di_with_web_forms
http://aspnetresources.com/articles/real_world_ioc_and_di_with_webforms

Hope this helps.