# How to use Ninject.Web.PageBase alongside another, custom .NET PageBase

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject-2

I am trying to get Ninject working with a WebForms application that already has a custom PageBase object. But, I don't know for sure if I can use Ninject's PageBase object alongside another, custom PageBase. I've been searching for a while now to see if I could find an answer to this problem, or to learn how to do it, but all I've found is this:

> I've hacked together an alternative using a shared base class that 
>   derives from Page. It looks roughly like this
>
> ```
> public abstract class PageBase : Page
> {
>   public IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }
>   public PageBase() { Kernel = ...; }
>   public void Page_Init() { Kernel.Inject(this); }
> }
> ```
>
> This will allow you to property and method injection on any pages that
>   inherit from PageBase. Note that the constructor is incomplete --
>   you'll  have to access the kernel in some static fashion. You should
>   be able to read  it from the HttpApplication somehow.

(source: http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/317fc48387399aa6, linked from [Ninject with ASP.Net webforms and MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141330/ninject-with-asp-net-webforms-and-mvc/3200931#3200931)):

This looks like it might work for me because it appears that I could apply this code to the existing, custom PageBase. But, I am hung up on the part in which the author says, "... the constructor is incomplete -- you'll  have to access the kernel in some static fashion."

Does anyone have any idea what that sentence means, and how one might go about accessing the Ninject kernel in a static fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to derive from a Ninject page base. You can alternatively use the NinjectHttpModule.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web/NinjectHttpModule.cs

Comment: Thank you, Remo. This seemed to work for me. But, I have another newbie question. How do I test this to make sure it's working? For example, do I need to do some sort of injection into an existing .aspx page in the code behind? I am still trying to wrap my head around how WebForms and DI (or IoC) work together.

Comment: The module injects each page and all its controlls on initialization of the page. The only thing you are not allowed is to access dependencies in your constructor. The only way to see if every thing is properly injected is to open the pages. If something is wrong you will immediately see it due to NullReferenceExceptions. Unfortunately there is no better way for WebForms. The only thing I can suggest is to implement any new page with MVC and probably port every page that needs to be extended to MVC too.

Comment: Gah ... this is hard. I've just realized that the source of my problems was the NinjectHttpModule. I'm not sure why yet, but when I use it, I end up getting errors from a custom Page object, from which the previously-mentioned custom PageBase class is derived. I was able to avoid getting this error by sticking with the standard System.Web.HttpApplication, and just calling IKernel CreateKernel as a non-abstract method. But, now I'm afraid I've broken DI in my app ... well, DI hasn't ever really worked yet, so I suppose I couldn't have -broken- it ...

Comment: Anyway, thank you VERY much for the advice you've given so far. I am very grateful.